# notations in navier stokes equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am reading navier stokes equation. And I have problem understanding
the definition of weak solution.

The incompressible navier stokes equation is written as$$\partial_tu+div(u\otimes u)-v\bigtriangleup u=-\bigtriangledown p$$$$divu=0$$$$u|_{t=0}=u_0$$

The weak solution is defined as a time-dependent vector field u with component in the space $L_{loc}^2((0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^d)$ if for any smooth, compactly supported, time-dependent, divergence-free vector field $\phi$, we have$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}u(t,x)\cdot\phi(t,x)dx=\int^t_0\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}(vu\cdot\bigtriangleup\phi+u\otimes u:\bigtriangledown\phi+u\cdot\partial_t\phi)(t',x)dxdt'+\int_{\mathbb{R}^du}u_0(x)\cdot\phi(0,x)dx$$I am confused about the notation :. What does it mean? I guess we get the definition of weak soution by "integration by parts". So it is a solution in the sense of distribution. But I don't know the notation :.Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not standard notation, and it's not obvious unless you do the calculation. It appears that the author means
$$A:B=\sum_{i,j}A_{ij}B_{ij}$$
where $A$ and $B$ are matrices of the same dimensions. We can see this by doing the formal integration by parts on the $\nabla\cdot(u\otimes u)$ as follows:
$$\int[\nabla\cdot(u\otimes u)]\cdot\phi=\int\sum_{i,j}\partial_i(u_iu_j)\phi_j=-\int\sum_{i,j}u_iu_j\partial_i\phi_j=-\int(u\otimes u):\nabla\phi$$
as was to be shown.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think it works.